# Setting up a sticky post tag in tumblr?

Tags: javascript, api, tumblr

Does anyone have any clues about how one might go about setting up a sticky post function using a special tag in tumblr? I know that the Single A theme has this functionality but there's no documentation and I'm trying to avoid decoding it all. Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would choose to use a specific tag for the post, say, 'sticky' and then run an API call only on posts tagged with Sticky, limiting to 1 (optional).

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/[YOURBLOG].tumblr.com/posts/?api_key=[YOURAPIKEY]&limit=1&tag=sticky
```

More info on the API can be found here: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts

The API call would look something like this in JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '[URL_FROM_ABOVE]&jsonp=?',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data){

        // do something with your data

    }

});
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but then would the sticky post not appear twice? , i.e. also in the normal theme post output? Is there a way to exclude posts with that tag from appearing in the normal output?

Comment: There might be a better way to go about it, but you can grab the post ID and then hide it from your page by inserting some CSS.

    $(document.body).append('<style type="text/css">/* styles here */</style>');

Comment: that makes sense @graygilmore, but somehow i was hoping there'd be a more elegant solution, say being able to modify/manipulate the data source that tumblr uses to output theme data in its special tags... but maybe no such thing exits. thanks for the help so far!